# How to validate jsPerf test output

Tags: validation, jsperf

Yesterday I was presented with a jsPerf test where the comparison was invalid, because the functions tested were actually not returning the correct result.

My question: is there a way to validate each test output directly in jsPerf?

Answer (score 0):

ok, not sure if there's a built in way, but for now I found a workaround that forces the test to error out:

```
if (//not the expected output) {it.is.not.working;}
```